# Behat, PHP Scenario outline: outputting param

Tags: php, testing, behat

Given the following behat scenario:

```
 Scenario Outline: Bootstrap pages does not encounter the following problems:
Given I am on "<page>"
And I should not see "�"

Examples:
| page                     |
| web.php                  |
| logs.php                 |
| web.php                  |
| payout.php               |
```

One of them if not passing returning:

```
0 scenario0 step0m0.02s (23.11Mb)
Given I am on "<page>"
And I should not see "�"

The text "�" appears in the text of this page, but it should not.

Skipped step
```

The problem is that I don't know which page is failing exactly because I have `"<page>"` instead of having the actual page. Does someone have an idea. I searched this on google and I did not find anything

Comment: You should run in verbose, meaning `-vvv` argument for Behat 3.

Comment: if you answer the question below I will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to have a detailed stack-trace of the error is to use verbose option.

Add `-v|-vv|-vvv` flag based on the level of details you need.